# Does SQL Server 2008 Web Edition support remote data connections?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm writing a .NET app that connects to a remote hosted SQL Server.  Researching hosts for when I roll this app out to multiple customers, I find that SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition is cheaper (monthly on a hosted dedicated server) than the Workgroup Edition and **much** cheaper than the Standard edition. Everything says Web Edition is for "website support" and "internet facing" use.

I know I must use Windows Server Standard and not Windows Server Web Edition to support database services, but what about the SQL Server version?

Simply - can a large number of users of a .NET Windows Forms program use a direct connection string to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition on the hosted server without going through a web server / browser?

Comment: Dave: can you access your SQL Server from a different server (e.g. for a website hosted on a physically separate IIS) ? I'm not sure if I asked the same thing here: http://serverfault.com/questions/359385/sql-server-2008-web-edition-access-from-another-iis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it supports remote data connections.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

From my understanding of Web Edition, it is basically a mid-liner between Express and Standard.  It's obviously not free, but it doesn't have the restrictions that Express does yet gives a lot of features (PBM, more than 1 CPU utilization, etc.).

Comment: Also uses more RAM - Up to 64 GB vs. 1 GB limit in Express.  But- what's PBM?

Comment: @DaveBecker Sorry, it stands for Policy-Based Management.